# Connecting arduino - serial port unavailable - yellow triangle against port in device manager

Tags: arduino, port, arduino-ide

I'm unable to connect my Arduino to serial port. The serial port option is grayed out. The device manager shows Arduino connected to port but has a yellow triangle sign against it. Have tried disconnecting/connecting it several times and updating software. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it by reinstalling my driver from device manager.